# local/global extremum

Tags: maxima-minima

Hi guys just wanted to clear up this notion of local/global extremum at an interior point. I would like to know what's the proper definition for a function having a local/global extremum.

I know a local extremum can be a maximum or minimum value while a global extremum can be the largest maximum or minimum value. As it relates ,  to defining it is there more to it or is this the general idea.

> $f$ has a global maximum at $x$ if $f(y) \leq f(x)$, where $f(y$) is the function values.
>
> The opposite is for the minimum where $f(x) \leq f(y)$
> and for the minimum a neighborhood is considered in each instance within the function.

Comment: Generally a problem has a feasible set $F$ (it may be the whole space). If $f$ has a global $\max$ at $x$ then $f(x) \ge f(y)$ for all $y \in F$. If $f$ has a local $\max$ at $x$ then there is some neighbourhood $B$ of $x$ such that $f(x) \ge f(y)$ for all $y \in F \cap  B$. Same for $\min$. Clearly a global $\max$ is a local $\max$.

Comment: so saying the function has a local or global extremum is really just saying it has a local or global maximum or minimum at an interior point of the set ? @copper.hat

Comment: Not in general. There is no mention of interior of set. For example, if the problem is $P:\ \ \min \{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) | x \ge 0 \}$ then the global $\min$ is at $x=0$, which is not in the interior.

Comment: The feasible set need not even have an interior.